# Would like to get build information from Google Cloud Profiler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-profiler

I'm using Google Cloud Profiler (located at https://console.cloud.google.com/profiler) and would like to know how my profiling data changes across different builds of my application.

One way to do that would be to check the range of dates during which a particular commit was running on production, but that's time consuming because I have to:

1. Get the start date/time of release, determine the date/time of the next release
2. Set those dates manually in the profiler interface from the link above

That's really not terrible, but it'd be great to be able to set `BUILD_ID` environment variable like I can in Cloud Build and then be able to access that from the UI. Is something like this possible? Or is my approach the best way to do this at the moment?

Comment: You may file a feature request from this page. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Answer (score 1):

You can set the service version for this purpose. Please refer to the agent documentation for how to set it for supported languages.

For example, [this](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-go#using-profiler) shows using `ServiceVersion` for `Go` services.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing across service versions would likely be a simpler and more precise way to do this (as opposed to using the time interval to select for profiles). To compare across service versions, it is necessary that the profiling agents set the service version.

The service version can be specified in the configuration passed to the agent (for the Go, Python, or Node.js agent) or via the `-cprof_service_version` flag (for the Java agent). If one is setting the service version using the configuration passed to the agent (applicable for the Go, Python, and Node.js agents), it may be convenient to use a flag or command line argument to set the service version so that the source code won't need to updated with each new version.

If one is running on Knative or App Engine standard, the service version should be auto-populated. These environments set the `K_REVISION` and `GAE_VERSION` environment variables (respectively), and the profiling agents (for all supported languages) use these environment variables to populate the service version. If one is running in another environment and modifying the source code is inconvenient or infeasible, one can set either the `K_REVISION` or `GAE_VERSION` environment variable in the environment running the application with the agent enabled to specify the service version.

My understanding is that the `BUILD_ID` is available at build time, but not at run time, so I don't know that it's possible for agents to use that directly.

(Disclosure: I work on Cloud Profiler at Google)